# Making list items out of object

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm making a project Node.JS project with Socket.io. I'm trying to make HTML list items from a object. I'm trying to prerender players list to this pug file I'll be rendering. Though, I can get the players list and display it in the html, but all the usernames clump together as one list item.

Things I've tried

**app.js**

```
var players = {}

socket.on('connection', function(socket) {
    players[socket.id] = {}
    var playerList = ''
    for (var i in players) {
        playerList += i + "<br>"
    }

    var roomData = pug.renderFile('./views/room.pug', {
        playerList: playerList
    })
})
```

The reason `players[socket.id] = {}` is a object and not array is because there is other stuff that does go in the object, it's just not included in here.

**room.pug**

```
.row
    .col.s12
        #test
            ul
              li
                |#{playerList}
```

As said before, the above method puts all the players in a single HTML list item. How can I seperate each player into their own list item? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
socket.on('connection', function(socket) {
    players[socket.id] = {}
    var roomData = pug.renderFile('./views/room.pug', {
        playerList: Object.keys(players)
    })
    // etc ...
})
```

and in Pug:

```
.row
    .col.s12
        #test
            ul
                each playerName in playerList
                    li= playerName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add all the fields of the object in a new list like this :

```
 var list;
 for (var key in object) {
        list.push(objet[key]);
 }
```

Comment: I mean to say HTML list item, not a js array.